# lightning:inputRichText defaults to 'Salesforce Sans' style and '12' size of text even when the selected text has a different style and font

Tags: lightning, aura, default-value, inputrichtext

In a Lightning component Rich Text area, selecting text style and size always defaults to Salesforce Sans and size 12.

Input some text into the editor then try to change the font style or size. See that it defaults to Salesforce Sans and Size 12.

Making a selection of a style or size does actually change it but every time you click the style dropdown it shows Salesforce Sans and Size 12.

**Using below Code** on Aura Component

```
 <pre>
      <lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.taskCommentRecord.Comment__c}" aura:id="taskCommentsId"/> 
 </pre>
```

**UI Issue of FontFamily and Size** Default below:

[image]

Comment: I have tried using doInit in controller: 
doInit: function(cmp) {
        var appliedFormats = {
                font: 'arial'
         };
        var editor = cmp.find("editor");
        editor.setFormat(appliedFormats);
    }

But still it is not applied to component.